# When to Add and/or Multiply Combinatorial Coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics

Though having read [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184115/in-need-of-tips-suggestions-when-to-add-or-multiply-probabilities) and [II](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/294878/53259), I still fail to understand when to add and/or multiply Combinatorial Coefficients. I exemplify my confusion:

> 1. **Multinomial Pascal's Rule** $\quad$ <sub>Source: 1.18, p 20, *A First Course in Pr* (8 Ed) by S Ross:</sub>
>
> $ \dbinom{n}{n_1,.....,n_{r - 1}, n_r} = \dbinom{n - 1}{n_1 - 1,.....,n_{r - 1}, n_r}  + ...  + \dbinom{n}{n_1,.....,n_{r - 1}, n_r - 1} $

2. Why add and not multiply?

> 3. <sub>1.10(d), p 18, *A First Course in Pr* (8 Ed) by S Ross:</sub>
>    $\dbinom{n}{k}k = \dbinom{n}{k - 1}[n - (k - 1)] = n\dbinom{n - 1}{k - 1}$

4. Without relying on the derivation below to explain, why cannot $\dbinom{n}{k}\color{green}{k} = \dbinom{n}{k} + k$?
5. Why cannot $\dbinom{n}{k}\color{green}{k} = n + \dbinom{n - 1}{k - 1}$?

<sub>I know, and so ask NOT, how to derive 3. From the definition of basic multiplication, $\dbinom{n}{k}\color{green}{k} = \underbrace{\binom{n}{k} + \cdots + \binom{n}{k}}_{k \text{  times }} $.

Since $\color{green}{k = \dbinom{k}{k - 1}}$, I tolerate that $\dbinom{n}{k}\color{green}{k} = \dbinom{n}{k}\color{green}{\dbinom{k}{k - 1}}.$</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the additive structure of the formula above more comprehensible, I'd like to analyse the identity

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{n_1,\dots,n_{r-1},n_r}&=\binom{n-1}{n_1-1,\dots,n_{r-1},n_r}\\
&\qquad+\cdots+\binom{n-1}{n_1,\dots,n_{r-1},n_r-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

from *three different* point of views.

Please note, that the multinomial coefficients of the RHS of the identity always show $n-1$.

> 1.) First view based on *combinatorial considerations*:

We show that $(1)$ is valid by using *classical* combinatorial arguments. We start with the binomial pendant:

> \begin{align*}
> \binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}\qquad 0<k\leq n\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ can be interpreted as the *number of different subsets of size $k$ from a set with $n$ elements*. And this is already the LHS of the identity. We now fix an element in the $n$-element set. We observe that when we consider the sets of size $k$ which *contain this specific element*, we can choose these sets in $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways. On the other hand, considering the sets of size $k$, which *don't contain* this specific element this can be done in $\binom{n-1}{k}$ ways. These two configurations are disjoint, so that $(1)$ is valid and we see, that we *sum up* the binomial coefficient since they represent numbers of *disjoint configurations*.

We now want to emphasize the *symmetry aspects* of $(2)$ using *multinomial coefficients* instead and changing variables: Let $n_1,n_2\geq0$ and $n_1+n_2=n$.

So, we can write identity $(2)$ as

> \begin{align*}
> \binom{n_1+n_2}{n_1,n_2}=\binom{n_1+n_2-1}{n_1-1,n_2}+\binom{n_1+n_2-1}{n_1,n_2-1}\qquad 0<n_1,n_2\leq n\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

We can also slightly modify the combinatorial argument above, by using the symmetry. We can say, that the *fixed* element of the $n$-element set is either in a subset with $n_1$ elements or in the disjoint subset with $n_2=n-n_1$ elements (the complement of course).
This *symmetrically* formulated argument can now be easily generalized to the identity $(1)$ with multinomial coefficients:

> The identity $(1)$ holds, since the LHS gives the number of possibilities to choose $r$ disjoint subsets with $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_r$ elements from a set having $n=n_1+\cdots+n_r$ elements.
>   Now the RHS: We fix an element and have $$\binom{(n_1-1)+n_2+\cdots+n_r}{n_1-1,n_2,\dots,n_r}$$ possibilities that this fixed element is part of the $n_1$-element subset, up to $$\binom{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_{r-1}+(n_r-1)}{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{r-1},n_r-1}$$ possibilities, that this fixed element is part of the last $n_r$-element subset. Since *all these constellations* are disjoint, the multinomial coefficients of the RHS are *summed up*, showing identity $(1)$ is valid.

$$ $$

> 2.) Second view based on *generating functions*:

Here we consider multinomial coefficients as coefficients of corresponding polynomials to show the additive structure of the identity $(1)$. First we consider the *binomial coefficient* $\binom{n}{k}$ as coefficient $[x^ky^{n-k}]$ of the polynomial $(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$:

> \begin{align*}
> \binom{n}{k}&=[x^ky^{n-k}](x+y)^n\\
> &=[x^ky^{n-k}](x+y)(x+y)^{n-1}\\
> &=[x^ky^{n-k}]x(x+y)^{n-1}+[x^ky^{n-k}]y(x+y)^{n-1}\\
> &=[x^{k-1}y^{n-k}](x+y)^{n-1}+[x^ky^{n-k-1}](x+y)^{n-1}\\
> &=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{n-k-1}\\
> &=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}
> \end{align*}

It's clear to see that the additive part of the RHS stems from the binom $x+y$

> Now analogously for multinomial coefficients. Let $n=n_1+\cdots+n_r$, $n_1,\dots,n_r\geq 0$. The following is valid:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{n}{n_1,\dots,n_r}&=[x^{n_1}\cdot...\cdot x^{n_r}](x_1+\cdots +x_r)^n\\
> &=[x^{n_1}\cdot...\cdot x^{n_r}](x_1+\cdots +x_r)(x_1+\cdots +x_r)^{n-1}\\
> &=[x^{n_1}\cdot...\cdot x^{n_r}]x_1(x_1+\cdots +x_r)^{n-1}\\
> &\qquad+\dots+[x^{n_1}\cdot...\cdot x^{n_r}]x_r(x_1+\cdots +x_r)^{n-1}\\
> &=[x^{n_1-1}\cdot...\cdot x^{n_r}](x_1+\cdots +x_r)^{n-1}\\
> &\qquad+\dots+[x^{n_1}\cdot...\cdot x^{n_r-1}](x_1+\cdots +x_r)^{n-1}\\
> &=\binom{n-1}{n_1-1,n_2\dots,n_r}+\cdots+\binom{n-1}{n_1,n_2\dots,n_r-1}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> 3.) Third view based on *lattice paths* in $\mathbb{R}^r$:

We start with the two-dimensional case and use multinomial coefficients from the beginning, since the symmetry is especially valuable in this case. We consider lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ with $x,y\in \mathbb{N_0}$. The walk along a lattice path is done in steps always having length $1$ and are either in east or in north direction.

The following is valid:

> The *number of lattice paths* of length $x+y$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ is 
>   $$\binom{x+y}{x,y}$$

Now, there are exactly *two* points $(x-1,y)$ and $(x,y-1)$ which are to pass one step before $(x,y)$ can be reached. The number of pathes from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ is therefore the number of pathes from $(0,0)$ to $(x-1,y)$ *plus* the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y-1)$. Therefore we get:
$$\binom{x+y}{x,y}=\binom{x+y-1}{x-1,y}+\binom{x+y-1}{x,y-1}$$

Now analogously for multinomial coefficients we can consider lattice paths in $\mathbb{R}^{r}$ from $(0,...,0)$ to $(x_1,\dots,x_r)$. We have $r$ points $(x_1-1,\dots,x_r)$ up to $(x_1,\dots,x_r-1)$ which are to pass one step before the endpoint can be reached. And we get in the same way as in the two-dimensional case the identity for the multinomial coefficients.

> Note: These are three different views which examine the *additive* structure of the identity with multinomial coefficients above. The essence is that *disjoint* configurations are used, so that summing up of the coefficients is feasible. As already mentioned by the answer from [vonbrand](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43946/vonbrand)

---

To give some arguments for *multiplicative* applications of binomial coefficients as proposed in the question, I think the example $10$ on page $18$ from the referenced book of *Ross* is quite instructive.

> Example 10: From a group of $n$ people, suppose that we want to choose a commitee of $k$, $k\leq n$, one of whom is to be designated as chairperson.

(a) By focusing *first on the choice of the committee* and *then on the choice of the chair* argue that there are $\binom{n}{k}k$ possible choices.

(b) By focusing *first on the choice of the nonchair committee members* and *then on the choice of the chair*, argue that there are $\binom{n}{k-1}(n-k+1)$ possible choices.

(c) By focusing *first on the choice of the chair* and *then on the choice of the other comittee members*, argue that there are $n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ possible choices.

(d) Conclude from parts (a), (b) and (c) that

$$k\binom{n}{k}=(n-k+1)\binom{n}{k-1}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

I think, these suggestive formulations already provide good hints to see why these identities are valid. And again, the essence also for these *multiplicative* examples is already given in the answer from [vonbrand](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43946/vonbrand).

Answer (score 0):

This can be summarized into two rules: **Addition rule:** The *union* of disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ has $\lvert A \rvert + \lvert B \rvert$ elements. **Multiplication rule:** The *cartesian product* (all ways to match up an $A$ with a $B$) of sets $A$ and $B$ has $\lvert A \rvert \cdot \lvert B \rvert$ elements.

Think how you are building up what you want to count from simpler pieces, this should tell you which one to apply.